# conversion to ASCII number

Tags: r

```
    > for (i in 1:(ncol(crypto$name))) {
    +   if (is.character(crypto$name[, i])==TRUE){
    +     for(j in 1:nrow(crypto$name)) {
    +       ascis <- as.numeric(charToRaw(crypto$name[j, i]))
    +       name[ j, i] <- sum(ascis)
    +     }
    +   }
    +   crypto$name[,i] <- as.numeric(crypto$name[,i])
    + }
    Error in 1:(ncol(crypto$name)) : argument of length 0
    >
```

I have been trying to change two columns in my dataset to ASCII but getting the error. i am at loss please I need help

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(crypto$name)))` , ncol is telling you something different, the number of columns from <- here to -> there, whereas $name is a column, and you want to do something with every member of the column, hence `length` as an approach. And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: thank you for your help, i discovered another error message                                                              > for (i in 1:length(crypto$name)) {
+   if (is.character(crypto$name[, i])==TRUE){
+     for(j in 1:nrow(crypto$name)) {
+       ascis <- as.numeric(charToRaw(crypto$name[j, i]))
+       name[ j, i] <- sum(ascis)
+     }
+   }
+   crypto$name[,i] <- as.numeric(crypto$name[,i])
+ }
Error in `[.default`(crypto$name, , i) : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: what is `class(crypto$name)` tell you?

Comment: it tells character Thanks

Comment: And how is `crypto$name <- as.numeric(crypto$name)` failing your purposes?, i.e. no loop should be needed.

Comment: Thanks still got the same error, Error in crypto$name[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: The `error` is referring to your use of `$name[, i]`, but `$name` all by itself, is [,i], it is the column and hence the right dimension, and `as.numeric(crypto$name)` is vectorized (solves a lot of problems, goes fast...) If you insist on a loop `$name[i]`.But again, if you want to change a character column to a numeric column, just try what I put before, forget the `for` loop. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Chris `as.numeric` does not transform character to their ascii values. eg `a` should have ascii value of 97 not `NA`

Comment: you could do: `sapply(crypto$name, function(x)sum(strtoi(charToRaw(x), '16')))`

Answer (score 0):

Change `ncol` to `nrow`. You need to loop over the rows and not columns.

The other parts also have a couple of syntax errors.

For instance, `crypto$name[, i]` is incorrect. It should be `crypto[i, "name"]`. You need to know about the difference between row and column references. The second loop over `j` is also something that I cannot figure out. Two loops over rows do not seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for:

```
sapply(crypto$name, function(x)sum(strtoi(charToRaw(x), '16')))
```

Comment: in the context, wouldn't this want to be `crypto$name <- unname(sapply(crypto$name, function(x)sum(strtoi(charToRaw(x), '16'))))`. And thanks for bringing clarity to what was more likely $name data, 'a', not' 1213'.